# Does monster power affect base dps and armor of items?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can ilvl 59-60 items compete with ilvl 61-63 items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/89243/can-ilvl-59-60-items-compete-with-ilvl-61-63-items)

In 1.0.5 turning on monster power makes all levels of inferno items able roll level 63 affixes.  Does this ability to roll higher stats affect base dps of weapons or base armor of items as well?

The main goal of this question is to determine what items should be discarded if they have no chance for rolling maximum stats.  Bonus points if you can determine the *likelihood* that lower level items can roll 63 affixes and base stats. I.E. Just because level 61 items can roll 63 affixes, doesn't mean they have an equal chance to do so.

Please include citations from primary sources or detailed analyses to receive an accepted answer to this question.

Comment: The above linked question has highly subjective answers depending on a player's goal.  My question is precise, technical, and answerable.

Comment: I fail to see the difference; item level no longer affects affix rolls at all.  It's all about monster level now.